# How to extract key,value pairs from hbase SequenceFile using mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, sequencefile

I used the `Hbase Export utility tool` to export a hbase table into HDFS as a `SequenceFile`.

And now I want to use a mapreduce job to process this file:

```
public class MapSequencefile {
        public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{
            @Override
            protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                    Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
                    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                System.out.println(key+"...."+value);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {  

            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Job job = Job.getInstance(conf , MapSequencefile.class.getSimpleName());

            job.setJarByClass(MapSequencefile.class);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
            job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
            job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class); //use SequenceFileInputFormat
            FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, "hdfs://192.16.31.10:8020/input/");
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://192.16.31.10:8020/out/"));
            job.waitForCompletion(true);
        }  
}
```

but it always throws this exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find a deserializer for the Value class: 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result'. Please ensure that the configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured, if you're using custom serialization.
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1964)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.initialize(SequenceFile.java:1811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1760)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.initialize(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:548)
```

What can i do to fix this error?

Comment: Hi did this solution solved your problem ?Me too facing the same kinda problem .Can you please suggest me some way out here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using this to do the export:

`$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export <tablename> <outputdir> [<versions> [<starttime> [<endtime>]]]`

As described on this HBase page: http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops_mgt.html#export

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/Export.java) for `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export` you can see it sets:

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Result.class);
```

Which aligns with your error (the Value is a `Result` object):

`Could not find a deserializer for the Value class: 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result'`

So your map signature needs to change to:

`Mapper<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result, Text, Text>`

And you'll need to include the correct HBase library in your project so it has access to:

`org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result`

Comment: Hi I am facing same problem not able to resolve it .Please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45728120/could-not-find-a-deserializer-for-the-value-class-org-apache-hadoop-hbase-clie

Comment: can you please look at my question once